# rosjava and android_core

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every one!!

I am trying to create a app for android who could run ros nodes. But i have a problem when i create it.

My enviroment is ros indigo, ubuntu 14.04, android-studio, rosjava and android_core packages.

First i create a package on my catkin_ws (catkin_create_rosjava_pkg) and after i create a project on rosjava  package (catkin_create_rosjava_project).

With that it doesn't create a android app structure or schema.  it didn't recognise "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" on the manifest or when i create a layout.

Do you know why it could be?

in case that i create a project from android-studio it is impossible for me import rosjava library!!!

Thank million for your help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205768/rosjava-and-android_core/) by [zior89](https://answers.ros.org/users/13176/zior89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Certainly catkin_create_android_xxx because it's an android project, not a rosjava project. Also there is no org.ros.android.Node class. Start by copying in one of the many other tutorials, compiling it, and then paying attention to what they've done.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0